# MATLAB accessing multiple elements in sparse matrix using row and column index vectors

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, matrix-indexing

I feel there should be an easy solution but I can't find it:

I have the sparse matrices `A` `B` with the same dimension `n*n`. I want to create matrix `C` which copies values in `A` where `B` is non-zero.

This is my approach:

```
[r,c,v] = find(B);

% now I'd like to create an array of values using indices r and c, 
% but this doesn't work (wrong syntax)
v2 = A(r,c);

% This won't work either
idx = find(B); % linear indexing, too high-dimensional
v2 = A(idx);

% and create C
C = sparse(r,c,v2,n,n);
```

Here are some more details:

- My matrices are very large, so the solution needs to be efficient. `C(B~=0) = B(B~=0);`  won't do it, unfortunately.
- Linear indexing won't work either as the matrices are too large (`Matrix is too large to return linear indices.`).

Is there really no way to use 2-dimensional indices?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you try `C = A .* (B~=0);` ?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, this works! If you want to post it as an answer I can formally accept it :)

Comment: Sure. I was not totally sure before you tried it on your data because we are talking about efficiency. Thanks for the credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `C = A .* (B~=0);` should work. Only non-zeros will be accessed in the entrywise multiplication of two sparse matrices so it will be fast.